# Как сверстать прозрачные цифры в круге?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, дизайн

Как сверстать прозрачные цифры в круге?

[image: как это сделать]

Comment: Самый простой вариант сделать кнопки в формате png с прозрачность и объединить их в один спрайт.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Можно:

1. Сделать эти кнопки-изображения с прозрачностью в области цифр.
2. С помощью clip-path сделать область отсечения в виде текста (цифры).

Если нужно чтобы они светились белым при наведении, то выровняйте сверху цифры и задайте значение цвета transparent, а при наведении поменяйте на белый.

Answer (score -1):

Можно вот так:

```css
img {
  position:absolute;
}
.button {
top:100px;
left:150px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 font-size: 48px;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius:100%;
 opacity: 0.5;
 filter: alpha(opacity=50);
 background: #000;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg">
<div class="button">3</div>
```